# $C^{*}$ algebras positively dominated by finite dimensional algebras

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Assume that $A$ is a  $C^{*}$ algebra and  $B$  and  $C$ are two sub $C^{*}$ algebras of  $A$ such that:

1. $B$ is  finite  dimensional algebra.
2. For all positive $c\in C$, there exist a positive $b\in B$ such that $c<b$.

Can we say that $C$ is finite dimensional algebra, too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ is any unital C*-algebra, the hypotheses are satisfied with $C=A$ and $B=\mathbb C1$.